# Inserting data into multiple tables using result of another table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using JDBC with MySql. I am inserting data into one table and getting its primary key `transactionid`. Now insert data with transactionid into another table.

My code:

```
if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("Now connection is created successfully");
        stmt=connection.createStatement();
        Date date=new Date();
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String time=formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("time is   "+time);
        //insert transaction id and minimum support....
        mySql = "insert into Transaction (minimumsupport)   
 values('"+minimumSupport+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(mySql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ResultSet rt=stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        int transactionId;
        while(rt.next()){
            transactionId=rt.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("the transaction id is: "+transactionId);
        }
        rt.close();

        int i;
        Statement stmt1;
        for(i=0;i<productArray.length;i++)
        {
            stmt=connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("first value: "+productArray[i]);
            mySql = "insert into 
                      Producttransaction(transactionid,productId)
   values('"+transactionId+"','"+productArray[i]+"')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(mySql);
            status="productAdded";
            System.out.println("product added");
        }
            //To insert the data into the tables....
        connection.close();
```

Throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aprioridb`.`Producttransaction`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Productid` FOREIGN KEY (`transactionid`) REFERENCES `Product` (`productId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your foreign key constraint is wrong:

```
FOREIGN KEY (transactionid) REFERENCES Product (productId)
```

should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES Product (productId)
```

Also, learn about prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks, have more robust and more efficient code.